Compiling the C++ code on UE5 takes too long
My system information:

CPU: i39100f, 16G mem, RX 590
Unreal Engine 5.2.1
Windows 10
Visaul Studio 2022

I've just create a default project and type some basic code like this
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "MyCharacter.h"

// Sets default values
AMyCharacter::AMyCharacter()
{
    // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

}


// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMyCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Hello World, I'm the firt in this line"));
}

// Called every frame
void AMyCharacter::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AMyCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, &AMyCharacter::MoveForward);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveRight", this, &AMyCharacter::MoveRight);
}

void AMyCharacter::MoveForward(float value) {
    FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(Controller->GetControlRotation()).GetScaledAxis(EAxis::X);
    AddMovementInput(Direction, value);
}

void AMyCharacter::MoveRight(float value) {
    FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(Controller->GetControlRotation()).GetScaledAxis(EAxis::Y);
    AddMovementInput(Direction, value);
}


I've trid to compile it. but it takes too long to compile even i just changed one character. It takes about 200 - 300 seconds to compile every times. The compile output is below:
1>Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
1>Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" StudyEditor Win64 Development -Project="G:\Source\Unreal\Study\Study.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild
1>Log file: C:\Users\qianx\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log.txt
1>Invalidating makefile for StudyEditor (MyCharacter.cpp.obj.response modified)
1>Building StudyEditor...
1>Using Visual Studio 2022 14.34.31948 toolchain (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933) and Windows 10.0.22621.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
1>[Upgrade]
1>[Upgrade] Using backward-compatible include order. The latest version of UE has changed the order of includes, which may require code changes. The current setting is:
1>[Upgrade]     IncludeOrderVersion = EngineIncludeOrderVersion.Unreal5_0
1>[Upgrade] Suppress this message by setting 'IncludeOrderVersion = EngineIncludeOrderVersion.Unreal5_2;' in StudyEditor.Target.cs.
1>[Upgrade] Alternatively you can set this to 'EngineIncludeOrderVersion.Latest' to always use the latest include order. This will potentially cause compile errors when integrating new versions of the engine.
1>[Upgrade]
1>Determining max actions to execute in parallel (4 physical cores, 4 logical cores)
1>  Executing up to 4 processes, one per physical core
1>  Requested 1.5 GB free memory per action, 1.91 GB available: limiting max parallel actions to 1
1>Building 9 actions with 1 process...
1>[1/9] Compile [x64] SharedPCH.Engine.ShadowErrors.InclOrderUnreal5_0.cpp
1>[2/9] Resource Default.rc2
1>[3/9] Compile [x64] MyCharacter.gen.cpp
1>[4/9] Compile [x64] MyCharacter.cpp
1>[5/9] Compile [x64] Study.init.gen.cpp
1>[6/9] Compile [x64] Study.cpp
1>[7/9] Link [x64] UnrealEditor-Study-0001.dll
1>  正在创建库 G:\Source\Unreal\Study\Intermediate\Build\Win64\x64\UnrealEditor\Development\Study\UnrealEditor-Study-0001.suppressed.lib 和对象 G:\Source\Unreal\Study\Intermediate\Build\Win64\x64\UnrealEditor\Development\Study\UnrealEditor-Study-0001.suppressed.exp
1>[8/9] Link [x64] UnrealEditor-Study-0001.lib
1>  正在创建库 G:\Source\Unreal\Study\Intermediate\Build\Win64\x64\UnrealEditor\Development\Study\UnrealEditor-Study-0001.lib 和对象 G:\Source\Unreal\Study\Intermediate\Build\Win64\x64\UnrealEditor\Development\Study\UnrealEditor-Study-0001.exp
1>[9/9] WriteMetadata StudyEditor.target
1>Total time in Parallel executor: 195.47 seconds
1>Total execution time: 200.62 seconds

It says that I did't have enough memory, but if even i free enough memory, Although the tips will disapear but the compiling still take extramley long time.

Maybe look into tools like ccache. There's also always the option of getting faster hardware.

Check the includes, if you are including any files that are not needed.

@jesper-juhl Is it normal for it to take so long?

@kiner-shah I've just included needed header files

@Qixiny I can't say, I have very different hardware (Ryzen 9 7950X & 64GB RAM and a super fast SSD).

What is G:? Is it some form of network drive? A hard disk? Unreal is a huge project and needs maximum disk performance to get reasonable compile times

Large projects can take a long time to compile. You could help this quite a bit by getting a system with more 16 cores or more and 4 times the ram you have. And make sure you have your code on a NVMe drive.
